# Savon do not show client.operations under HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, savon

I have problem with getting operation from WSDL after setting up https. I'm  trying to get operations from this wsdl:

`https://test.processing.kz/CNPMerchantWebServices/CNPMerchantWebService.wsdl`

If I do it from my localhost or server without https, I successfully get a list of available operations. But when I configured my nginx to serve https, operations can not be obtained (no matter what ssl_verify_mode is enabled). I just receive an empty array.

```
> client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'https://test.processing.kz/CNPMerchantWebServices/CNPMerchantWebService.wsdl', ssl_verify_mode: :none, log: true) 
 => #<Savon::Client:0x00000005f27a88 @globals=#<Savon::GlobalOptions:0x00000005f27a60 @option_type=:global, @options={:encoding=>"UTF-8", :soap_version=>1, :namespaces=>{}, :logger=>#<Logger:0x00000005f279e8 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00000005f279c0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00000005f27970 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x00000005f27920 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000005f278a8>>>>, :log=>true, :filters=>[], :pretty_print_xml=>false, :raise_errors=>true, :strip_namespaces=>true, :convert_response_tags_to=>#<Proc:0x00000005f27830@/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.0/lib/savon/options.rb:85 (lambda)>, :convert_attributes_to=>#<Proc:0x00000005f27808@/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.0/lib/savon/options.rb:86 (lambda)>, :multipart=>false, :adapter=>nil, :use_wsa_headers=>false, :no_message_tag=>false, :follow_redirects=>false, :unwrap=>false, :wsdl=>"https://test.processing.kz/CNPMerchantWebServices/CNPMerchantWebService.wsdl", :ssl_verify_mode=>:none}>, @wsdl=#<Wasabi::Document:0x00000005f276c8 @document="https://test.processing.kz/CNPMerchantWebServices/CNPMerchantWebService.wsdl", @adapter=nil, @request=#<HTTPI::Request:0x00000005f27678 @follow_redirect=false, @auth=#<HTTPI::Auth::Config:0x00000005f27628 @ssl=#<HTTPI::Auth::SSL:0x00000005f27600 @verify_mode=:none>>>>> 
2.1.3 :046 > client.operations
D, [2015-05-25T17:31:41.817858 #25654] DEBUG -- : HTTPI GET request to test.processing.kz (net_http)
 => []
```

My nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name my_server;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/my_cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/ssl/my_cert.key;

  root /home/deployer/qiwiexline/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;

  location ^~ /assets/
  { gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```